# Grails 2.0 schema-export

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

My Grails 2.0 app seems to be trying to connect to my production database when I run:

```
grails prod schema-export
```

I just want the DDL for the production DB.  This didn't happen with Grails 1.3.7.  Did this change between versions?

Comment: The script didn't change but the version of Hibernate did, and the script is just a wrapper for Hibernate's SchemaExport tool. I don't know what changed specifically there but that's where you'd want to look.

Comment: It seems to work fine if I comment out the database URL.  I may dig a bit deeper into this.